# netbeans strikeiron web server connection reset

Tags: java, ajax, appletviewer

Introduction:
I’m attempting create a real time web application (java - maven over NetBeans) from original SCADA application and use the NetBeans strikeiron GlobalSMSPro service as an gadget to obtain a asynchronous connection while infinitely poll the field IEDs by internal tcp connection in the field host connecting by serial port (running the field host as a gateway).-

Topic of interest:

In the applet.class within the method callAsyncronousCallBack() I changed:

```
com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro service = new com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro();
```

by

```
com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro service = new com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro(new URL("http://ws.strikeiron.com/SMSAlerts4?WSDL"),javax.xml.namespace.QName.valueOf(“http://wsparam.strikeiron.com/SMSAlerts4?WSDL”));
```

In the client DOS window of the appletviewer I’ve got the following message:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://wsparam.strikeiron.com/SMSAlerts4?WSDL. It failed with: Got connection reset while opening stream from://wsparam.strikeiron.com/SMSAlerts4?WSDL
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.Runtimewsdlparser.tryWithMax<RuntimeWSDLParser.java:173>
```

..............
Ing. Raúl José Puccinelli
Equipos Eléctricos – Empresa Provincial de la Energía – Santa Fe - Argentina - 12-09-2012

Answer (score 0):

I try without any firewall and changed:

> `com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro service = new com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro(new URL("http://ws.strikeiron.com/SMSAlerts4?WSDL"),javax.xml.namespace.QName.valueOf(“http://wsparam.strikeiron.com/SMSAlerts4?WSDL”));`

by:

> `com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro service = new com.strikeiron.GlobalSMSPro(new URL("http://ws.strikeiron.com/SMSAlerts4?WSDL"),javax.xml.namespace.QName.valueOf("{http://www.strikeiron.com}GlobalSMSPro"));`